# Remove noise from threshold image opencv python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to get the corners of the box in image. Following are example images, their threshold results and on the right after the arrow are the results that I need. You might have seen these images before too on slack because I am using these images for my example questions on slack.

[image]

Following is the code that allows me reach till the middle image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img_file = 'C:/Users/box.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(img_file, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img = cv2.blur(img, (5, 5))

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv)

thresh0 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(s, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)
thresh1 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(v, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)
thresh2 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(v, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)
thresh = cv2.bitwise_or(thresh0, thresh1)

cv2.imshow('Image-thresh0', thresh0)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imshow('Image-thresh1', thresh1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imshow('Image-thresh2', thresh2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Is there any method in opencv that can do it for me. I tried dilation `cv2.dilate()` and erosion `cv2.erode()` but it doesn't work in my cases.Or if not then what could be alternative ways of doing it ? 
Thanks

Canny version of the image ... On the left with low  threshold and on the right with high threshold

[image]

Comment: To my knowledge, canny + erosion should work. Can you upload the images so as to see why it doesn't work for you?

Comment: Consider accepting an answer if you managed to solve the problem or post your own solution so others can benefit.

Answer (score 21):

Below is a python implementation of @dhanushka's approach

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load color image
im = cv2.imread('input.jpg')

# smooth the image with alternative closing and opening
# with an enlarging kernel
morph = im.copy()

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, 1))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (2, 2))

# take morphological gradient
gradient_image = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT, kernel)

# split the gradient image into channels
image_channels = np.split(np.asarray(gradient_image), 3, axis=2)

channel_height, channel_width, _ = image_channels[0].shape

# apply Otsu threshold to each channel
for i in range(0, 3):
    _, image_channels[i] = cv2.threshold(~image_channels[i], 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU | cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    image_channels[i] = np.reshape(image_channels[i], newshape=(channel_height, channel_width, 1))

# merge the channels
image_channels = np.concatenate((image_channels[0], image_channels[1], image_channels[2]), axis=2)

# save the denoised image
cv2.imwrite('output.jpg', image_channels)
```

The above code doesn't give good results if the image you are dealing are invoices(or has large amount of text on a white background).
In order to get good results on such images, remove

```
gradient_image = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT, kernel)
```

and pass `morph` obj to the split function and remove the `~` symbol inside for loop

Comment: Thank you so much, that saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Thank you! This is so much better than all the garbage methods like Canny which leave a ton of excess noise.

Comment: What should I do if  I want to convert those edges into a shape e.g. entire box into a black shape

Answer (score 16):

You can smooth the image to some degree by applying alternative morphological closing and opening operations with an enlarging structuring element.Here are the original and smoothed versions.

[image: im][image: smooth]
[image: im2][image: smooth2]

Then take the morphological gradient of the image.

[image: grad]
[image: grad2]

Then apply Otsu threshold to each of the channels, and merge those channels.

[image: merged]
[image: merged2]

If your image sizes are different (larger), you might want to either change some of the parameters of the code or resize the images roughly to the sizes used here. The code is in `c++` but it won't be difficult to port it to `python`.

```
/* load color image */
Mat im = imread(INPUT_FOLDER_PATH + string("2.jpg"));
/* 
smooth the image with alternative closing and opening
with an enlarging kernel
*/
Mat morph = im.clone();
for (int r = 1; r < 4; r++)
{
    Mat kernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(2*r+1, 2*r+1));
    morphologyEx(morph, morph, CV_MOP_CLOSE, kernel);
    morphologyEx(morph, morph, CV_MOP_OPEN, kernel);
}
/* take morphological gradient */
Mat mgrad;
Mat kernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(3, 3));
morphologyEx(morph, mgrad, CV_MOP_GRADIENT, kernel);

Mat ch[3], merged;
/* split the gradient image into channels */
split(mgrad, ch);
/* apply Otsu threshold to each channel */
threshold(ch[0], ch[0], 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);
threshold(ch[1], ch[1], 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);
threshold(ch[2], ch[2], 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);
/* merge the channels */
merge(ch, 3, merged);
```

Comment: Wow. That is a clever way to do it. I'm amazed at the left-vs-right pictures where everything has been smoothed with the opening and closing.

Comment: nice method, indeed, could I select min and max sizes to the contours in images?, I plan to classify images

Comment: @DanielSaito Not clear what you mean by "min and max sizes to the contours"? As post-processing you can find contours and do any processing.

Comment: @dhanushka sorry haha, I meant to remove small contours that are considered noise but this algorithm doesn't remove as well as the ones that are too big. After get the contours, only use the ones that are in a range min<X<max. Trying to understand how to limit this

Answer (score 6):

Not sure about how robust that solution will be but the idea is pretty simple. The edges of the box should be more pronounced than all the other high frequencies on those images. Thus using some basic preprocessing should allow to emphasize them.

I used your code to make a prototype but the contour finding doesn't have to be the right path. Also sorry for the iterative unsharp masking - didn't have time to adjust the parameters.

[image: result]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def unsharp_mask(img, blur_size = (9,9), imgWeight = 1.5, gaussianWeight = -0.5):
    gaussian = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5,5), 0)
    return cv2.addWeighted(img, imgWeight, gaussian, gaussianWeight, 0)

img_file = 'box.png'
img = cv2.imread(img_file, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img = cv2.blur(img, (5, 5))
img = unsharp_mask(img)
img = unsharp_mask(img)
img = unsharp_mask(img)

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv)

thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(s, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)
_, contours, heirarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)
#for cnt in cnts:
canvas_for_contours = thresh.copy()
cv2.drawContours(thresh, cnts[:-1], 0, (0,255,0), 3)
cv2.drawContours(canvas_for_contours, contours, 0, (0,255,0), 3)
cv2.imshow('Result', canvas_for_contours - thresh)
cv2.imwrite("result.jpg", canvas_for_contours - thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

### method 1: using AI models

always try image segmentation models if feasible to your project, robust models will work better on a wider domain than any thresholding technique.
for example [Rembg](https://github.com/danielgatis/rembg) , try online on a [Huggingface space](https://huggingface.co/spaces/KenjieDec/RemBG)
here are the results:
[image] [image]

### method 2:

almost similar to other answers but with another approach.

1. instead of closing and opening to blur the "noise", we use `cv2.bilateralFilter` which is similar to photoshop's surface blur, [read more](https://machinelearningknowledge.ai/bilateral-filtering-in-python-opencv-with-cv2-bilateralfilter/)

```
im = cv2.imread('1.png')
blur = cv2.bilateralFilter(im,21,75,75)
```

[image]
[image]

2. use sobel filter to find edges

```
from skimage.filters import sobel
gray = cv2.cvtColor(blur,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
mm = sobel(gray)
mm = ((mm/mm.max())*255).astype('uint8')
```

[image]

3. apply thresholding, I use [Sauvola Thresholding](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_niblack_sauvola.html) here:

```
from skimage.filters import threshold_sauvola

mm2 = np.invert(mm)
thresh_sauvola = threshold_sauvola(mm2, window_size=51)
th = mm2 < thresh_sauvola
```

[image]

4. dilate and fill holes:

```
def fill_hole(input_mask):
  h, w = input_mask.shape
  canvas = np.zeros((h + 2, w + 2), np.uint8)
  canvas[1:h + 1, 1:w + 1] = input_mask.copy()
  mask = np.zeros((h + 4, w + 4), np.uint8)
  cv2.floodFill(canvas, mask, (0, 0), 1)
  canvas = canvas[1:h + 1, 1:w + 1].astype(np.bool)

  return ~canvas | input_mask

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (2,2))
th2 =cv2.morphologyEx((th*255).astype('uint8'), cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel) 
filled = fill_hole(th2==255)
```

[image]