# How to remove external hollow contours from the image without affecting the internal contours

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

This is a continuation of a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58277734/removing-line-artifacts-from-an-image) under a different approach.

I want to get rid of the boxes, and everything outside of its lines, and keep whatever's inside the box, as is. Or at least only the box.

The box:

[image: img]

How I want it to look like after doing some magic:

[image: img]

This is where it was cropped from:

[image: img]

If you view the first image on a black background, you'll notice there's still a white band beyond the boxed field. It can be cropped smaller or larger by getting its bounding box's stats, and adding the padding into it.

This is the naive and my first approach. The problem here is:

- It cannot account for different line widths too much without affecting the characters inside. Say, you put in -9 as padding. It will work mostly well enough on boxes with ~9px line width, but anything beyond the ~9px are left inside. This causes some leftover pixels, which ultimately affects the accuracy of my application.
- On the other hand, any boxed field with line width significantly lower than 9 may then have the characters inside destroyed too.

My second attempt is [removing the contour](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/02/09/removing-contours-image-using-python-opencv/) with a mask. However, it didn't turn out as expected.

The code in extracting the contours is really long so just assume `stats` contains the `contours` returned from `contours, _ = cv2.findContours`

```py
# loop in each contour in stats
for i in range(len(stats)):
    # get the stats of the bounding rectangle 
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(stats[i])

    # draw the field contour into the mask
    cv2.drawContours(mask, [stats[i]], -1, 0, -1)

    # remove the contour from the original image
    section = cv2.bitwise_and(section, section, mask=mask)

    # crop the boxed field
    field = crop_by_origin(x, y, w, h, padding=p)
```

This is what I get:

[image: img]

I don't understand why it didn't work? Maybe it's because in the site his example is on a black background? Maybe it doesn't work with "transparent" contours? Is this even possible?

How to fix this? Any other possible solutions around here?

UPDATE

I tried another image with @nathancy's answer and this is what came up:

[image: img]

The result:

[image: img]

I tried playing around with the horizontal line kernel but it didn't work out as intended, is there a way to make this more dynamic?

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be broken down into two separate steps. First, we want to isolate the rectangles which can be done using contour approximation + filtering. Then we remove the horizontal and vertical lines with the implementation borrowed from a previous answer in [removing horizontal lines in image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274961/removing-horizontal-lines-in-image-opencv-python-matplotlib). Here's an overall approach:

- Convert image to grayscale and Gaussian blur
- Otsu's threshold to get binary image
- Find contours and use contour approximation to find rectangle boxes

  - If a contour passes this filter and minimum threshold area, use Numpy slicing to copy-paste the ROI onto a blank white mask
- Remove horizontal lines
- Remove vertical lines
- Bitwise-and mask with input image to get result

---

Otsu's Threshold `->` Detected boxes `->` Boxes drawn onto mask `->` Inverted

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Remove horizontal lines `->` Remove vertical lines `->` Bitwise-and to get result

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
mask = np.ones(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8) * 255
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7,7), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.05 * peri, True)
    if len(approx) == 4 and area > 500:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
        mask[y:y+h, x:x+w] = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]

# Remove horizontal lines
mask = cv2.cvtColor(255 - mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (50,2))
detect_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=1)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_horizontal, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (0,0,0), 6)

# Remove vertical lines
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (2,45))
detect_vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=1)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_vertical, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (0,0,0), 6)

# Bitwise mask with input image
result = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)
result[mask==0] = (255,255,255)

cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: I'm curious, why do you always use `threshold` when preprocessing the image? Am I missing some vital step in image processing in not using it, does it provide better results even if the image was thresholded before, or just a habit of yours?

Comment: Tested it on multiple images, doesn't work reliably considering the fact that the border thickness is varying, and that some characters (particularly 1's) got erased partly or fully too. Is there a way to like, grab the contents inside the boxed field minus the border, or get its bounding box? Since I have some filters in place, I guess it's okay if there's some minimal noise left.

Comment: Thresholding gives a binary image, meaning the pixel value is 0 for black or 255 for white, it allows to segment desired sections of the image. Another method to get a binary image is to use Canny edge detection. In this case, thresholding isn't necessary but I think its a good step in the pipeline. You can lower then thickness parameter in cv2.drawcontours, 9 is quite a lot. The bounding box for each rectangle was used to draw the mask, so the bounding box was obtained in a intermediate step

Comment: I tried a different approach, as I still can't make this work reliably, sorry. The goal of my new approach was to extract the contour inside the boxes, not the one outside, by cropping its bounding box to a new image. I found out I can use `cv2.RETR_CCOMP` for this. While this minimizes the border edge artifacts after blurring and thresholding such that it can't be detected, it can't account for the fact where the inside character/s bisects the interior contour into two. I'll try yours again..

Comment: There's another approach, once you get the mask (boxes drawn onto mask image), create a horizontal kernel then dilate/morph_close to merge the numbers together into a single contour. From there, find contours and filter using contour area. This will guarantee work if the numbers are not touching the box, but if they are touching, this method will run into problems. I still recommend tinkering with the draw contours thickness and using this current vertical/horizontal lines removal approach. A 3rd approach is to use contour hierarchy but again, will have problems with touching boxes

Comment: Is it possible to make your solution more dynamic? I updated the post and uploaded a case that has its horizontal lines untouched..

Comment: Yes you can modify the horizontal/vertical kernel sizes to remove more or less. Check the updated code, works for your new image