# Remove noise from threshold TEXT images in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have these images:
[image]

I want to remove the noise from the background(i.e make the background white in 1st and 3rd and black in 2nd) in all these images, I tried this method: [Remove noise from threshold image opencv python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42065405/remove-noise-from-threshold-image-opencv-python) but it didn't work, how can I do it?

P.S
This is the original image that I am trying to enhance.
[image]

Comment: You can try cleaning it up using erosion and dilation if you haven't done that yet

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You show noisy images, but then you show your original image, which is already clean. Which images do you want to process - the 3 noisy ones or the 1 good one?

Comment: @fmw42 Actually I want to enhance the original image... i.e the handwriting should become dark(er) and the background pure white... I am doing this to train my ML model

Comment: Just use cv2.adaptiveThreshold on that image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use adaptive threshold on your original image in Python/OpenCV

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread("writing.jpg")

# convert img to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# do adaptive threshold on gray image
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 21, 10)

# write results to disk
cv2.imwrite("writing_thresh.jpg", thresh)

# display it
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]